# Does fspy add-on work in blender 2.81?

Tags: add-on, camera, fspy

I have tried installing fspy in blender 2.81, however it says it is 'installed' (as can be seen in attached image) but then doesn't appear in add-ons list, and hence cannot be enabled.

[image: it says 'file installed']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You installed the wrong file; you need to install `fSpy-Blender-1.0.3.zip`
 (or newer) from [the Releases](https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases) page.

The file you're using, `fspy-Blender-master.zip` is likely the source code and doesn't work as addon.

It's not very clearly stated on the page and it's easy to download the wrong file(I had the same issue :)

Answer (score 1):

The [latest fSpy addon release](https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases/latest) works for blender 2.81 on Linux ( but this should also work on all other systems ).

[image: fSpy addon info]

Answer (score 1):

Fspy version 1.0.3, confirmed to be working with Blender 2.81 for Windows, can be downloaded from [Github](https://github.com/SavMartin/fSpy-Blender)

Comment: works for Mac too, I downloaded the wrong file accidentally lol